# display icons instead of magento grid action lables

Tags: magento, grid, icons

How to display icons instead of action labels in magento admin grid. Ex: I need to display image icons instead of 'edit'/'delete rows in grid

thanks,
murali

Comment: is there any possibility to display icons. i did different ways but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done this issue by using css.Simply Add to action array your new class like

```
$this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
            'align'     =>'center',
                'getter'    => 'getAnswerId',

         'actions'   => array(          
           array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/delete'),
                'confirm'  => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Are you sure?'),
                       'class'     => 'addm',


                    )
             ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'store',
                'is_system' => true,


        ));
```

And write your new css with this code :

```
.addm{
    background-image:url('delete.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
     text-indent:-9999px !important;
     font-size:0px;
     display:block;
    margin-left:5px;

    }.
```

You have done.